# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un array de objetos y ponerle más datos en Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vuex

```
new Vue({
        el: '#main',
        data:{
            arrayD:[
        { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
         { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
         { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
         { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' }


      ]
        },
        methods:{
            ponerdatos: function(){
                for(i in this.arrayD){
                    this.arrayD[i].push({
            title:'titulo'
          })

                }
            }
        }
})
```

https://codepen.io/jv_13/pen/JywNMm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Push` agrega un elemento a un `array` y lo que desea es añadir una propiedad a un elemento que no es posible con push.

Sí lo que desea es añadir una nueva propiedad para un objeto con `Vue` debería emplear [Vue.set()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). de la siguiente forma . Si desea añadir más de una propiedad *(ojo que se agregan a todos los objetos del array)* podría duplicar la línea.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data:{
        arrayD:[
    { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
     { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
     { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' },
     { body:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' }
      
    
  ]
    },
    methods:{
        ponerdatos: function(){
            for(i in this.arrayD){
                this.$set(this.arrayD[i], 'title', "titulo"); 
                this.$set(this.arrayD[i], 'descripcion', "mi descripcion");
            }
           /* O Haciendo uso de forEach , solo descomentar esta linea */
           //this.arrayD.forEach((ob)=> this.$set(ob, 'title', "titulo"));
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <button @click="ponerdatos()">meter</button>
    <pre>
        {{ $data }}
    </pre>
</div>
```

Sí desea añadir un nuevo elemento al `array` ahí puede emplear `push` directamente

```
this.arrayD.push({"body": "nuevo item" , "title" : "nuevo titulo"})
```

Comment: Gracias, pero porque el push no funciona?

Comment: `Push` agrega un elemento a un array y lo que desea es añadir una propiedad a un elemento que no es posible con push. Ahora Vue trata diferente las propiedades de los objetos para que sean reactivas por eso se hace uso se set

Comment: Y como se usa para pasar mas datos al objeto?: https://codepen.io/jv_13/pen/JywNMm

Comment: Estimado, me refiero de ir agregando mas key: valor sumándolos al objeto ya existente, por ejemplo this.$set(this.arrayD[i], 'title', "titulo") le quiero agregar mas key: valor pero no agregarle un nuevo item al array

Comment: @JuanVargas agregar clave valor a un objeto ya existente, se hace como en la primera parte de mi  respuesta que incluso ya tiene implementado en su codepen _(no agrega un nuevo item al array , agrega una propiedad)_, si desea agregar otra solo duplicacaria la línea con otra propiedad a agregar. si es algo diferente no logro  captar la idea de lo que desea hacer.

Comment: de esta forma  duplicaria la línea con otra propiedad a agregar:https://codepen.io/jv_13/pen/JywNMm     Gracias.

Comment: @JuanVargas si una respuesta le  ayuda a resolver su duda no olvide aceptarla. Saludos.